# Как сделать опциональным параметр в теле запроса? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

В модели делаю так:

```
public class Network
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

В контроллере делаю так:

```
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Network network)
{
    ...
}
```

Затем делаю так:

```
services.AddControllers(options => {options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true; })
```

В теле запроса передаю так:

```
{
    "ShortName": "test"
}
```

В конце всё равно получаю ошибку `400 Bad Request`

Comment: А если сделать `Nullable` тип (`int?`, `string?` и т.д.)?

Comment: Абсолютно верно. В модели сделал ```public string? Name { get; set; }``` Сработало, спасибо